Application Crashing and not continuing to layout_2 when Continue button is clicked (Android Studio)
There are no errors in the java, but when I try to run my code in my phone (I had to run it in my phone because my Android Studio is so slow) it's crashing. I will provide some of my codes in my java.
package com.vlsqz.activity2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        // Populate spinner with options (Samsung and Apple)
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spinner_items, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Handle continue button click
        findViewById(R.id.continue_button).setOnClickListener(view -> {
            String selectedItem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, layout_2.class);
            intent.putExtra("selectedItem", selectedItem);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
    }
}


package com.vlsqz.activity2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class layout_2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GridLayout gridLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_2);

        // Retrieve selected item from Intent extras
        String selectedItem = getIntent().getStringExtra("selectedItem");

        // Log the selectedItem to see if it's received correctly
        Log.d("Layout_2", "Selected Item: " + selectedItem);

        // Initialize GridLayout
        gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);

        // Check if gridLayout is null
        if(gridLayout == null) {
            Log.e("Layout_2", "GridLayout is null");
            return;
        }

        // Populate GridLayout based on the selected item
        if (selectedItem.equals("Samsung")) {
            addProducts(getSamsungProducts());
        } else {
            // If selectedItem is not "Samsung", handle it accordingly
            // For example, you can display a message or do nothing
            Log.e("Layout_2", "Invalid selected item: " + selectedItem);
        }
    }



    private void addProducts(Product[] products) {
        for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            // Find the IDs dynamically based on the item index
            int itemId = getResources().getIdentifier("item" + (i + 1) + "_layout", "id", getPackageName());
            GridLayout itemLayout = gridLayout.findViewById(itemId);

            // Find other view IDs within the item layout
            ImageView imageView = itemLayout.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("image" + (i + 1), "id", getPackageName()));
            TextView nameTextView = itemLayout.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("itemName" + (i + 1), "id", getPackageName()));
            TextView priceTextView = itemLayout.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("itemPrice" + (i + 1), "id", getPackageName()));
            EditText qtyEditText = itemLayout.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("editQty" + (i + 1), "id", getPackageName()));
            Button decButton = itemLayout.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("dec" + (i + 1), "id", getPackageName()));
            Button incButton = itemLayout.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("inc" + (i + 1), "id", getPackageName()));
            Button addButton = itemLayout.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("add" + (i + 1), "id", getPackageName()));

            // Set product data to views
            imageView.setImageResource(products[i].getImageResId());
            nameTextView.setText(products[i].getName());
            priceTextView.setText(products[i].getPrice());
            qtyEditText.setText("1"); // Assuming default quantity is 1

            // Add click listeners to buttons if needed

            // Add the item layout to the GridLayout
            gridLayout.addView(itemLayout);
        }
    }

    // Dummy method to get Samsung products
    private Product[] getSamsungProducts() {
        return new Product[]{
                new Product(R.drawable.galaxy_s24_ultra, "Galaxy S24 Ultra", "₱87,990.00"),
                new Product(R.drawable.galaxy_tab_s9, "Galaxy Tab S9 Ultra 5G", "₱85,990.00"),
                new Product(R.drawable.galaxy_watch_6, "Galaxy Watch 6", "₱18,990.00"),
                new Product(R.drawable.galaxy_buds, "Galaxy Buds 2 Pro", "₱12,990.00"),
                // Add more Samsung products as needed
        };
    }

    // Dummy method to get Apple products
    private Product[] getAppleProducts() {
        return new Product[]{
                new Product(R.drawable.macbook_pro, "MacBook Pro", "₱104,990.00"),
                new Product(R.drawable.iphone_15_pro, "iPhone 15 Pro Max", "₱70,990.00"),
                new Product(R.drawable.ipad_pro, "iPad Pro", "₱55,990"),
                new Product(R.drawable.apple_watch, "Apple Watch Ultra 2", "₱54,990.00"),
                // Add more Apple products as needed
        };
    }
}



I want to display all the items inside the layout_2.xml and want to run it, but it keeps crashing as I clicked Continue button layout_2.xml

If you run your app on the device directly from Android Studio, there's a crash log in Logcat. Have a look at Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?. The crash log will pinpoint the problem.

Removed android-studio tag as this question has nothing to do with the Android Studio product.

You need to loook at the logcat to see where the crash occured and the reason for it.

Thank you guys! I already fixed it, thanks!
